# How to use the python interpreter while another python process is running?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, vtk, pythoninterpreter

I use Python 3.6 and start a process in my script (VTK Visualization). Until I close the visualization window the command line is blocked which I want to change. I read something about multiprocessing and threading, but I'm not sure which is the right approach.

This is what I want to achieve and my ideas:

- start two processes (visualization window and a loop for inputs)
- with exec(input) the inputs are written into my script
- after that the visualization window is updated

I am thankful for any advice on which method could be suitable for my intend!

Edit: I tried threading and started both threads, but still the command line was blocked until I closed the window and just opened up again after typing in an input.. Is there anyone who achieved something similar before?

Comment: Threading probably.  Multiprocessing would create separate processes making communication between the two harder than threading.

Comment: [You'll have to use multiprocessing through threads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing
p = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
p.map(VTZ,args)
p.close()
```

this will open the vtz visualizations on 1 seperate thread. 
if you are passing information between threads, you must have Pipe() arguments. which is a much more complicated.

another way.
    import os
    import threading

```
t2 = threading.Thread(os.sys('python programName')
t2.start()
```

os.sys('python programName') this calls the command prompt and enters args for you. by doing this it's virtually impossible to pass information back and fourth between windows.